# function is not working when passing arguments to addEventListener

Tags: javascript

Making simple slider with Js, when passing function with arguments to addEventListernet slider is not working but when putting onclick="slide(1)" to ID, it works fine. What i'm doing wrong?

```
var imgcount = 1;
var imgTotal = 5;

var left = document.querySelector(".left");
var right = document.querySelector(".right");

function slide(x) {
    var img = document.getElementById("img");
    imgcount = imgcount + x;
    img.src = "img/"+ imgcount +".jpg";
}

left.addEventListener('click', slide(-1));
right.addEventListener('click', slide(1))

);
```

Comment: Oh, the same mistake. Calling the function directly. Either use anonymous function and call `slide` from inside it or use `.bind()`. **Code:** `left.addEventListener('click', function() { slide(-1)}); right.addEventListener('click', function() { slide(1) });`

Comment: You are calling the method and applying what it returns to the event handler.

Comment: This has been asked many times. Please use the search before you ask a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in order to do it the way you've started, you need to return a `function` from `slide`:

```
function slide(x) {
   return function(){
      var img = document.getElementById("img");
      imgcount = imgcount + x;
      img.src = "img/"+ imgcount +".jpg";
   }
}
```